# preg_match for php for the date

Tags: php, preg-match

How to use php to preg_match the string in the following case?

the string will be like 20150923_1111. The date format if this case would be Ymd_Hi.

Just wondering whether it would be achievable to validate the date format.

I just need to make sure the string is in digit and with the same length and does not have to validate the actual time.

Comment: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] This is the format, is it achievable by using preg_match or something similar in php? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want your regex to check if the string is 8 digits, followed by an underscore, followed by 4 digits. So, you could use `preg_match` like this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}$/', $input)) {
  // Process here
}
```

The `^` represents the start of the string, `[0-9]{x}` means look for the quantity `x` number of digits 0-9 in a row, and the `$` represents the end of the string.